# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A' while updating M2M

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to update a ManyToMany field in django while doing this I am getting the following error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 55, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/tutorialdb/api/views.py", line 94, in tutorials
    updateDB.tags.add(t)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 938, in add
    through_defaults=through_defaults,
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1065, in _add_items
    '%s__in' % target_field_name: new_ids,
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1251, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 59, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "/home/bhupesh/Desktop/tutorialdb-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

Here is my **models.py**

```
class tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class tutorial(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.URLField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = TUTORIAL_CATEGORIES)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    @cached_property
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am actually generating ***title*** & ***tags*** from a custom script that's why the serialzer is incomplete.

I am trying to send the following JSON data :

```
{
"link":"https://youtu.be/DHvMXvCVQVA",
"category":"video"
}
```

**views.py**

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def tutorials(request):
    """
    get: Returns all tutorials

    post: POST a tutorial
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tutorials = tutorial.objects.all()
        serializer = tutorialSerializer(tutorials, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        postserializer = tutorialPOST(data = request.data)
        if postserializer.is_valid():
            title, tags = generateTags(request.data['link'])
            print(title)
            print(tags)
            updateDB = tutorial.objects.create(
                title = title,
                link = request.data['link'],
                category = request.data['category'],
                created_date = timezone.now
            )
            for t in tags:
                updateDB.tags.set(t)

            return JSONResponse({"message " : "submitted" }, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        return JSONResponse({"message":"not_valid"})
```

Here is **serializer.py**

```py
class tutorialPOST(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = tutorial
        fields = ('link', 'category')
```

From what I know it's happening because of the following line in views.py

```
updateDB.tags.add(t)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing error ? Can you please update your question with more/full error logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `timezone.now` method, instead of passing the method itself:

```
        updateDB = tutorial.objects.create(
            title = title,
            link = request.data['link'],
            category = request.data['category'],
            created_date = timezone.now()
        )
```

You have default value of `created_date` set correctly:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

so it will be autofilled automatically for you:

```
        updateDB = tutorial.objects.create(
            title = title,
            link = request.data['link'],
            category = request.data['category']
        )
```

Comment: I removed the line, now it's giving me ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney Its another mistake in your code. You have to share whole traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your date fields are  giving errors. Just remove all their attributes and add "auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True" to date fields.

Comment: Welcome, @Naveen! Just a small hint: You can use backticks (\`) around your code to make sure its `formatted` as code.